# Find second minimum - algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I want to find the second minimum for three numbers.

I have a blackbox that gets two input numbers, the blackbox returns the max between numbers.

Additionally, I have a blackbox that returns the min.

Now I have a box that gets 3 numbers as input and it needs to return the second min.

Can you help me to solve this?
How can I solve this by only using the two blackboxes?

Thanks!

Comment: Amongst the three numbers, is the second min as the one that's neither the min nor the max?  If that's the definition of "second min", then it's also the solution to the problem

Answer (score 1):

I can see of a way to to this with 3 uses of the blackbox. Let's pretend each element is a,b,c. Find the min of a with b and b with c. You then find the max of those 2 answers and you have the second min. If only b was returned, you find the min of a and c.

Comment: The problem is that there is no "if" or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
Inputs: a, b, c

Level 1 (filtering out the biggest value):
min(a,b) -> min_ab
min(a,c) -> min_ac
min(b,c) -> min_bc

Level 2 (selecting the highest remaining value, step 1):
max(min_ab, min_bc) -> m*

Level 3 (step 2):
max(m*, min_ac) -> solution

Gives a total of 5 boxes.

a --+--\
    |   min --\
b -----<       max --\
    |   min --/       max --
c -----<             /
    |   min --------/
    \--/

Alternatively you can do 3 maxes first and then 2 mins.
```